# Dart Sass version 1.23.0-module.beta.1 is incompatible with ^1.3.0

Tags: sass

I'm implementing `socket.io` in laravel to make a chat system. When i run command `npm run dev` the following error occurred.

```
Error: Dart Sass version 1.23.0-module.beta.1 is incompatible with ^1.3.0.
```

I don't know what its about. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: deleting ```yarn.lock``` and ```node_modules``` then reinstalling seems to have fixed this for me

Answer (score 3):

I added the following to my `devDependencies` in my package.json:

`"sass": "^1.22.0",`

This seems to have solved the issue for me. To clarify I didn't install sass directly until I came across this issue.

Based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796735/error-dart-sass-version-1-23-0-module-beta-1-is-incompatible-with-1-3-0).